# How to get common category among columns in SQL

Tags: sql

Consider the following schema for SQL:

```
Student (StudID, StudName, DeptID, Age, Gpa);

Course (CourseID, CourseName, InstructorID);

Department (DeptID, DeptName, Location);

Instructor (InstructorID, InstructorName, DeptID);

Section (SectionID, SectionName, Time, RoomID, CourseID, InstructorID);

Room (RoomID, RoomName, Location);

Enrolled (StudID, SectionID);
```

**Q:** How to find the names of all sections that either meet in common room or have five or more students enrolled?

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure if it will work:)

Common names;

```
select st.StudName as names from Student as st inner join Departmant as d
on st.DeptID = d.DeptID inner join Instructor as i 
on i.DeptID = d.DeptID inner join Course as c
on c.InstructorID = i.InstructorID inner join Section as s
on s.InstructorID = i.InstructorID inner join Room as r
on r.RoomID = s.RoomID inner join Enrolled as e
on e.StudID = st.StudID;
```

More than 5 student enrolled(Something experimental:);

```
select st.StudName as names from Student as st inner join Departmant as d
on st.DeptID = d.DeptID inner join Instructor as i 
on i.DeptID = d.DeptID inner join Course as c
on c.InstructorID = i.InstructorID inner join Section as s
on s.InstructorID = i.InstructorID inner join Room as r
on r.RoomID = s.RoomID inner join Enrolled as e
on e.StudID = st.StudID where count(e.StudID = st.StudID)>4;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL-Server you can write the query like this(I didn't tested it. So I can't say it works 100% but I hope it gives you an idea):

```
SELECT SectionName 
        FROM Section
                WHERE SectionID IN --Students in common room.
                    (
                        SELECT SectionID FROM Section
                            INNER JOIN Instructor ON Section.SectionID = Instructor.InstructorID --Section to which the Instructor belongs
                            INNER JOIN Department ON Department.DeptID = Instructor.DeptID --Department to which the Instructor belongs
                            INNER JOIN Room ON Room.Location = Department.Location --Room to which the Department belongs
                    )
                    OR --Student Enrollment greater than 5.
                    (
                      (SELECT COUNT(StudID) FROM Student
                            INNER JOIN Enrolled ON Student.StudID = Enrolled.StudID
                            INNER JOIN Section ON Section.SectionID = Enrolled.SectionID) >= 5
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Q:6.    Find the names of all sections that either meet in room New-8 or have five or more students enrolled.

Answer:

```
select sectionName
from student as S, Enrolled as E, Section as Se
where S.studId=E.studId AND E.sectionID=se.SectionID
group by sectionName
having count(*)>=3

UNION

SELECT sectionName
FROM SECTION S, ROOM R
WHERE S.RoomID=R.ROOMID AND R.RoomName='new2'
```

this is the correct query i have run it on Db